# MVC2 with mySQL and LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm following an example out of my MVC2 book (ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework).  My question is regarding LINQ to SQL and a mySQL database.  The books examples connects to SQLServer, I am connecting to a mySQL database.

So far I have been able to connect to the DB and pull records...  However, I'm noticing that I'm erroring on the following LINQ statement:

```
        return View(productsRepository.Products
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize)
            .ToList()
            );
```

I've read that LINQ to SQL didn't originally support mySQL, however, with the mySQL .Net connector did that change?  Is LINQ to SQL fully supported for mySQL now?

Are there any references that would help me understand the differences if mySQL is still not supported fully?

Thanks

BTW the error message I'm getting is:

***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY `t0`.`ProductId`, `t0`.`Name`, `t0`.`Description`, `t0`.`Price`, `t0`.' at line 3***

Comment: If your pages are zero-indexed (meaning they count 0,1,2,...,n rather than 1,2,3,...,n) then that means your first page would skip `-1 * PageSize`, a negative number. What happens if you remove `-1 * ` from your code (assuming your pages are zero-indexed)?

Comment: @KPthunder - I thought about that as well, however, after I took out the - 1, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to SQL only supports SQL Server.

If MySQL support is required you should try using another ORM, such as Entity Framework or NHibernate.

In regards to the error thrown when trying to execute the query above, it is due to the fact that the SQL syntax used by SQL Server for paging is dramatically different to what is used by other relational databases.

Comment: @simon - that is what I was afraid of...  Are there any options that I might have with MVC2 and mySQL?

Comment: @Jeff - I've updated my answer. Please do ask more again if you have more questions.

Comment: @Jeff, NHibernate has Linq support. It works a little differently than Linq2Sql, but can be connected to nearly any relational store.

Comment: @Simon - Thanks I saw that...  @Jason - I'm following an example from the MVC2 book I bought.  I kind of what to learn it how he is presenting it and then expand out from there.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JeffV - If you want to learn it how it's presented, is there a reason you can't use SQL Server Express?  It's free.

Comment: @Michael - To be totally honest I was thinking of creating a site and I noticed a lot of the hosts use mySQL  (i.e cheaper), so that was the reason why I wanted to use mySQL.  Now that I know that I can't (at least for linq to sql), I have installed SSE and will continue learning using that.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/)

Comment: It looks like it hasn't been updated since 2008...  If that is the case that is too bad.  Thanks for the link though.